# Inequalities, Why $-3 \le n$ equals to $-3,-2 ... $ and not $-3,-4 ...$?

Tags: inequality

> #### Why $-3 \le n$ equals to $-3,-2 ...$ and not $-3,-4, -5 ... ?$

I just don't get it ?

I know that $3$ is lesser than $4$.

But in this case the answer is the opposite,that's why it makes me a bit confused.So if someone could explain i would really appreciate.

Except if the answer for $-3 \le n$ is different?since i figure that out through a program.

Comment: Ask yourself is $-4\ge-3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$-3\le n \iff n\ge -3$$

which means

$$n=-3,-2,-1,0,1,\dots$$

indeed integers are ordered as follows

$$\dots< -3< -2< -1< 0< 1< 2< 3< \dots$$

Comment: This doesn't really OPs question since they already acknowledge that they know that $-3 \leq n \implies n \geq -3$.

Comment: @ShonVerch Yes you are right! I've added the key point.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\dots,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,&\color{blue}{-3},&\color{blue}{-2},\color{blue}{-1},\color{blue}{0},\color{blue}{1},\color{blue}{2},\color{blue}{3},\color{blue}{4},\color{blue}{5},\dots\\&-3\leq n\\&\end{array}$$

I seem to remember in elementary school something about "the alligator likes to eat more food" something along those lines as a way to remember which side should correspond to the larger item.  The only remaining possible confusion as I can see it is in remembering that $-2$ is larger than $-3$ while $-4$ is smaller than $-3$.  Well, that should be clear from looking at the number line laid out like this.  "Larger" here corresponds to being further to the right, not to having higher absolute value.

This should remind you of how addition as it relates to negative numbers works as well.  Recall that $-3 + 1 = -2$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another useful perspective is to consider the more general case of $$x \leq n.$$ I think this is pretty clear what this is saying: for some variable input of $x$, it *must* be less than or equal to some constant $n$.

The converse is that if $x$ is a constant then this inequality means that any variable input of $n$ *must* be greater than or equal to some constant $x$. If it were not, it would braak the inequality (e.g. if $n=x-1$ then $x\leq x-1$  is obviously not true... In fact, $x \leq x-1$ is not true in general if $i\geq 0$).

I know that was a fair bit of abstraction to your simple problem so let's try a numerical example. If $x=3$ then we have $3 \leq n$. Once again, this inequality would *not* be true for any value less than $3$ since $3$ is not less than any value less than $3$.

Indeed, you are thinking in terms of absolute number terms, not in terms of their integral values. In your example, $-4$ *smaller* or *less than* $-3$ which is why it does not satisfy the inequality.